# Enable multithreading of my web app using python Bottle framework

Tags: python, multithreading, http, wsgi, web-frameworks

I have a web app written with Bottle framework. It have a global somedict list accessed by multiple HTTP query.

After some researching, I find that the Bottle framework only support 1 thread in 1 process mode to run my app(I don't believe it is true, perhaps migrating it to other frameworks like Flask is a good idea.).

1 To enable multi-threading, I find WSGI solution but it does not support multiple processs(1 threads for each process) accessing global variable like somedict in my app, because process will re-init the list every time a query gets handled. How can I handle this issue?

2 Is there any other solutions except WSGI that solve the problem to enable this app to serve multiple HTTP query at once?

```
from bottle import request, route
import threading

somedict = {}
somedict_lock = threading.Lock()

@route("/read")
def read():
    with somedict_lock:
        return somedict

@route("/write", method="POST")
def write():
    with somedict_lock:
        somedict[request.forms.get("key1")] = request.forms.get("value1")
        somedict[request.forms.get("key2")] = request.forms.get("value2")
```

Comment: Save data in database.

Comment: @furas, I really need a global queue in the memory, other frameworks like java !Play support this.

Comment: Use Redis if you want fast CRUD access to an in-memory store.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to serve a WSGI app via a server like gunicorn or waitress, which will handle your concurrency needs, but almost no matter what you do for concurrency your global queue in memory will not work the way you want it to.  You need to use an external memory store like memcached, redis, etc. Static data is one thing, but mutable state should never be shared between web app processes.  That's contrary to Python web server idioms and the typical execution model of Python web apps.

I'm not saying it's literally impossible to do in Python, but it's not the way Python solves this problem.

Comment: Is gunicorn have the same functionality with uWSGI of nginx

Answer (score 1):

You can process incoming requests asynchronously, currently Celery seems very suitable for running asynchronous tasks. [Read how Celery can do this.](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html)